# CodeIgniter / dbForge - multiple keys

Tags: php, codeigniter, dbforge

Im using CodeIgniters DBforge to use my database.

Im trying to convert a plain PHP script to CodeIgniter and im having some trouble with changing the SQL to dbforge.

I have the following SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE `message2_recips` (
  `mid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default 'N',
  KEY `m2r1` USING BTREE (`mid`,`status`),
  KEY `m2r2` USING BTREE (`uid`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Everything works fine except when i get to the 2 key values at the bottom.

Everything i have tried doesnt seem to work including,

```
$this->dbforge->add_key(array('mid', 'status'));
$this->dbforge->add_key(array('uid', 'status'));
```

Any help translating this would be greatly appreciated, i cant seem to find any way to input this using dbforge, which brings my project to a complete standstill

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use the normal DB class and SQL to create the table?

Comment: @TimWithers - For this project i thought i would try out migrations as its all source controlled and i wanted to deploy to various places without touching the DB ... I read that dbforge was the way to do it

Comment: The CodeIgniter documentation says that:
"...add_key() must be followed by a call to create_table()" - 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html

Could that be causing the issue? Also, dbForge is really just a handy wrapper for SQL functionality - I've found that I've had to extend it a few times to build in the flexibility that I need.

Comment: @adomnom Hey, when i run the add_key that i have in my post, it throws up an error saying that there are 2 status keys, except if you have a look at the raw SQL, they are named and i cant find this ... is there any way i can use raw SQL in the migration file to create the table instead of using codeigniters db wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to do (currently) via DB Forge - it doesn't support additional options for table keys. You can only achieve that by adding them afterwards with raw SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in DB_forge.php

You need to remove is_array condition to enable multiple keys (in mysql driver there is function to convert the array key to multiple key).

DBForge.php:101

Remove:

```
    if (is_array($key))
    {
        foreach ($key as $one)
        {
            $this->add_key($one, $primary);
        }

        return;
    }
```